# Spivak, Ch 14, Prob 2(viii): Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f$, and $f(x)=1$ if $x=1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(x)=0$ otherwise. At which points is $F'(x)=f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

The following is a problem from Ch. 14 "The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus", from Spivak's Calculus

> 2. (viii) Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f$.
>
> Consider the function
> $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } x=1/n \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}, \\ 0, \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$
>
> At which points $x$ is $F'(x)=f(x)$?

I believe the graph of $f$ looks something like

[image]

The solution manual solution is that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for

> All $x$ not of the form $1/n$ for some natural number $n$.

This is just the answer, but I am interested in a complete proof.

**Below is my attempt at a solution.** I'd like to know if it is correct.

> **Proof**
>
> First let's consider intervals of form $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$.
>
> Since $f$ is continuous on such intervals, we can use the first
> fundamental theorem of calculus to conclude that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for $x
>  \in \left (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right )$.
>
> The same argument applies for for $x \in (-\infty,0]$, where $F'(x)$ is
> also equal to $f(x)$ by the FTC1.
>
> **What about at points $1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}$?**
>
> If we can show that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ then we can infer
> that $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.
>
> > $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$
> >
> > **Proof**
> >
> > Let $P$ be any partition of $[0,1]$.
> >
> > $L(f,P)=\sum m_i \Delta t_i = 0$
> >
> > Let $I$ be the set of all $i$ such that $\Delta t_i=t_i-t_{i-1}$
> > contains a number $1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that this set contains
> > infinite points.
> >
> > $U(f,P)=\sum\limits_{i \in I} 1 \cdot \Delta t_i$
> >
> > For any $\epsilon>0$, if we choose the partition such that
> > $\sum\limits_{i \in I} \Delta t_i<\epsilon$, then $U(f,P)<\epsilon$
> > and $U(f,P)-L(f,P<\epsilon$.
> >
> > Thus, for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a partition $P$ such that
> > $U(f,P)-L(f,P)<\epsilon$. Thus $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.
> > $\blacksquare$
>
> I am note sure if I can justify the step where I assume we can make
> $\sum\limits_{i \in I} \Delta t_i<\epsilon$. How do I justify it?
>
> At this point we have
>
> - $F$ continuous on $[0,1]$
> - for all points $y=\frac{1}{n}$, $F'$ exists for all $x$ in an interval containing $y$ and we have $\lim\limits_{x \to y} F'(x)=0$
> - Then, we can infer (based on Theorem 7, Ch. 11, Spivak's *Calculus*, which basically says that derivatives can't have jump discontinuities)
>   that $F'(y)$ exists and $F'(y)=\lim\limits_{x \to y} F'(x)=0$
> - But then, at such points $y=1/n$, $F'(y)=0\neq f(y)=1$
>
> Thus $F'(x)=f(x)$ at all points except those points $y=1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: $F(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yes, so is the proof correct?

Comment: Note that your proof that $f$ is integrable (see the answer on how to complete this) also shows that the integral equals zero, so the rest follows without the need to cite further propositions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the partition to make $ U(f,P)\lt \epsilon $ can be attained as follows. Correct me if I am wrong.

For any $\epsilon \gt 0$, $\exists N$  s.t.  $\frac{1}{N} \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$;

Thus $ \left[0, \frac{1}{N} \right] $ can be covered by $ \left[0,\frac{\epsilon}{2}\right]  $.

For the points $\frac{1}{k}, k = 1, 2, 3, ..., N-1$, we cover each point by an interval of length $\frac{\epsilon}{2N}$ (smaller if necessary).

Then the total length of the intervals covering the points with non-zero functional values would be

$$ \frac{\epsilon}{2}+(N-1)\frac{\epsilon}{2N} \lt \epsilon $$

Hence

$$ U(f,P)\lt \epsilon $$